Not seeing my Xs or Checks in my Javascript todo list
I'm creating a simple TODO list with stardew valley themeing where on the page I can see my list of things for my day. I can't see any of the x's or check marks on the page. The idea is that I can click on an 'x' next to my task to remove it. I've gone through and made sure I'm calling everything properly as well as looked for errors but I am still drawing blank.


// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  // Attach event handler for the new "X" button
  span.onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}
/* Include the padding and border in an element's total width and height */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url(stardew_background.png);
}


/* Remove margins and padding from the list */

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Style the list items */

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  /* make the list items unselectable */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Set all odd list items to a different color (zebra-stripes) */

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}


/* Darker background-color on hover */

ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}


/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */

ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}


/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */

ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}


/* Style the close button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}


/* Style the header */

.header {
  background-color: #f44336;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Clear floats after the header */

.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Style the input */

input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* Style the "Add" button */

.addBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
  <h2>My To Do List</h2>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li>Water Crops</li>
  <li> Check coop</li>
  <li>give gift to sweetie</li>
  <li>visit mines</li>
</ul>




Could there be more css that's hiding these icons? I put your code from here straight into jsfiddle and I can see the x's and checkmarks.

I can see the x and checkmarks on the fiddle ... I guess there are some more CSS that is hiding them

Inspect the code, see if you can find the elements in question, and check the css to determine what may be hiding them.

Browser Dev tools would be helpful - go into source and find crosses and checks in the HTML, and further inspect each to see the CSS that's applied.
